# Dev Express Xtra Report Print button not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, devexpress, xtrareport

When I click on the print button it doesn't pop up print dialog box. Instead of it shows an error message saying "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" .This print functions works properly on localhost.Please refer the screen shot for the further information.

My devExpress Version is 15.2.15.0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to be related to the Chrome browser's PDF viewer specifics. To resolve this issue, disable Chrome's built-in PDF viewer and use the Adobe PDF viewer instead.

Go to chrome`://settings/content/pdfDocuments` (open pdf using different application)